# Paste postprocess TinyMCE wrapping methods?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

In my project, necessary to paste from word.docx where many elements, for example table. I got cleanup  attributes "width" of the inserted tables like this:

```
        paste_postprocess: function(editor, fragment) {
        var allTables = fragment.node.getElementsByTagName('table'); 
        for (let i = 0; i < allTables.length; ++i) { 
        var tab = allTables[i].removeAttribute('width'); 
        }
```

Are there any methods"paste_postprocess" to wrapping all the inserted tables in "div" ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found way

```
             var tables = fragment.node.getElementsByTagName('table'); 
              for (let i = 0; i < tables.length; ++i) { 
             var div = document.createElement("div");
              div.className = "table_scroll";
             var tablesdiv = tables[i].parentNode.insertBefore(div, tables[i]);
              div.appendChild(tables[i]);
               }
```

seems to work